# Nem a variável nem o campo aparecem depois de selecionado

Tags: html, formulário

Tenho um SELECT que depende de outro SELECT para trazer os valores. Porém, após selecionado o segundo select, apesar da url conter o valor desejado, o campo some.

```
$bandorc = isset($_GET['bandorc'])?$_GET['bandorc']:"";
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">
      <form method="get" name="tBand" id="cBand" style="float:left;margin-top:0px;">
        <select name="menu1" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
            <option value="">Selecione a Bandeira</option>
<?php
      $qry="SELECT sjy_empresas.bandeira AS id_bandeira,     
            sjy_bandeira.bandeira
            FROM kcb_tbstates 
            INNER JOIN sjy_bandeira 
            INNER JOIN sjy_grupo 
            INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_grupo.id_grupo = sjy_empresas.grupo
            AND sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira
            AND kcb_tbstates.ID = sjy_empresas.estado
            WHERE sjy_empresas.grupo = '$grupo'
            GROUP BY sjy_empresas.bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira";
      // Executa a consulta OU mostra uma mensagem de erro
      $rs = $MySQLi->query($qry) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

      // Faz um loop, passando por todos os resultados encontrados              
      while ($dt        = $rs->fetch_object()) {
            $band       = $dt->id_bandeira;
            $bandeira   = $dt->bandeira;


            echo "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=". $fnc . "&ans=" . $linha . "&bandorc=" . $band . "'>" . $bandeira . "</option>";
    }
?>  
            </select> 
      </form>
    </td>
    <td width="*">      
      <form method="get" name="tLoja" id="cLoja" style="float:left; padding-left:15px;margin-top:0px;">
        <select name="menu2" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
            <option value="">Selecione a loja</option>
            <?php   
    $sql="SELECT 
            sjy_empresas.id_empresa, 
            sjy_empresas.nick, 
            sjy_empresas.bandeira AS band, 
            sjy_bandeira.bandeira
          FROM sjy_bandeira 
          INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira
            WHERE sjy_empresas.grupo = $grupo
            AND id_bandeira = $bandorc";
      // Executa a consulta OU mostra uma mensagem de erro
      $rset = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

      // Faz um loop, passando por todos os resultados encontrados              
      while ($dt        = $rset->fetch_object()) {
            $empr       = $dt->id_empresa;
            $nick       = $dt->nick;
            echo    "<option value='premorc.php?fnc=". $fnc . "&ans=" . $linha . "&emp=" . $lj . "'>" . $nick . "</option>";
            }

            ?>

            </select>           
        </form>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <form action="../inc/processa.php" method="post">
        <input name="emp" type="text" value="<?php echo $empr; ?>" /> - Filial da Premissa: <?php echo $nick; ?> // Esse campo não aparece no navegador

    </form>
```

Comment: Qual a diferença para a sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249107/5878)?

Comment: Na pergunta anterior não aparecia o segundo select. Nessa não aparece o campo após o segundi select (é a última linha)